# Listen Only as Barge

Tags: twilio, bots, twilio-twiml

So I have a script that I need to read to the caller that is about 30 mins long.

Along the way the customer may interrupt the read and ask a question.

The callers question needs to be addressed, and then the read needs to continue from just before where it was interrupted.

so to track progress I store a session variable with a step number.

I say a sentence or two of the script.
|
I listen with barge true

then I redirect to the next section of the script.

this creates a pause waiting for caller response after the say and prior to the redirect.

UGH....
so I create a twilio function that checks the step and adds steps above the current step. the result looks like this

```
    {
            "Action": [
                    { "Say":"This is a couple sentences..." },
                    {"Remember":{"Step":1}},
                    { "Say":"This is a couple sentences..." },
                    {"Remember":{"Step":2}},
                    { "Say":"This is a couple sentences..." },
                    {"Remember":{"Step":3}},
                    { "Say":"This is a couple sentences..." },
                    {"Remember":{"Step":4}},
                    {"Listen":{"barge":true},
                    {"Redirect":"task://goodbye"}
            ]
    }
```

Only problem here is the Multiple Remembers calls that are used to identify where the read has been heard cause an error.

Any Ideas would be excellent!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Since all the actions are returned at the same time in the response from the Twilio Function all the "Remember" actions effectively run at the same time. So in your example, you are trying to write the same "Remember" step with different values at the same time and thus an error.

After reading what you did, I was going to suggest the redirect method, but you already explained that wasn't working for you.

If you can use regular TwiML, instead of Autopilot, you could try using [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather) with nested `<Say>` elements to read the script. When `<Gather>` doesn't receive a response from a user it continues to the next TwiML element in the document. So, if you set up several `<Gather>`s in a row with short timeouts and added the step to the [`action` URL](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather#action) you could replicate this behaviour.

For example:

```xml
<Response>
  <Gather action="/speech?step=1" timeout="1">
    <Say>First sentences</Say>
  </Gather>
  <Gather action="/speech?step=2" timeout="1">
    <Say>Next sentences</Say>
  </Gather>
  ... etc ...
</Response>
```

Does that help at all?

Comment: So, with auto pilot I'm able to determine the callers intent based on what they say.  This allows me to determine the question that caller has and provide the appropriate answer.

 Can similar intent based processing be performed using regular TWIML?  Or can gather be placed in A TWIML function and call from auto pilot?

Comment: You can't get intents from regular TwiML, no, that is what Autopilot is for. What you could do is handle the flow of saying and interrupting with Gather, then [send any gathered speech to your Autopilot bot through the custom channel interface](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/channels/custom-channel). That way you can combine the behaviour of Gather and the natural language processing of Autopilot.

Comment: Thank you Philnash you were a great help. That works perfectly.

Comment: Oh excellent! This is a use-case I'd not seen before, so it was a bit of a shot in the dark. Really glad it worked out for you.